# How can I permanently display the path of the current file in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I know <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> displays the current file you're working on. Is there a way to modify my `.vimrc` such that the filename/path is always displayed?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

In your statusline, add a `%F` to display the full path:

```
:help statusline

" Add full file path to your existing statusline
set statusline+=%F
```

Note, `%F` will be the full path.  To get a path relative to the working directory, use `%f`.

If your statusline is not already visible, you may first need to configure it to be always visible, via `laststatus=2`

```
set laststatus=2
```

See `:help laststatus` for what the options mean. Normally, the statusline may be hidden, or hidden unless multiple buffers are open, but I find it extremely useful to have on all the time with customizations like this, well worth giving up one screen line reserve for it.

Comment: I certainly prefer your answer to mine, but adding `set statusline+=%F` to my `~/.vimrc` doesn't seem to do what your saying.  Although the docs certainly seem to agree with you...

Comment: This had no effect. Apologies if Im missing something simple, do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: @TimPote What vim version? Works for me.  Maybe your statusline is already pushing it off or limiting width.  Try just `:set statusline=%F` without the `+`

Comment: @zallarak See my comment to Tim.  Does your statusline change if you simply do `:set statusline=%F`? Look way over to the right or left to see if the filename is hiding over there in the statusline

Comment: @Michael version 7.3.353.  `:set statusline=%F` does nothing as well.  Let me track down my current statusline settings.

Comment: @TimPote Maybe `set laststatus=2` to keep the statusline visible all the time.  I forgot I had that on.

Comment: @Michael Ah, I see.  It isn't in the standard line that shows the line/column number, etc.

Comment: @TimPote That's the ruler, the statusline is a lot more robust and capable.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375240/a-more-useful-statusline-in-vim

Comment: Sweet.  +1 for bringing in the statusline then.

Comment: I believe some vim extensions will steal the statusline (e.g. syntastic) for their own use, so using `set title` as in one of the other answers might be better for some people.

Answer (score 20):

set ls=2

add this in vimrc,
and you will see the file name at the bottom always.

Comment: set modeline didn't do anything for me, what is it suppose to do? (set ls=2 did do something though). How do I man/help to figure this out on my own the next time? Thanks! :)

Comment: `set modeline` is a bit dangerous and has nothing to do with the question. It allows the execution of Vim commands in the 5 beginning/ending lines of a file. It should be turned on only by those who knows why and really want this. (Thats why I -1 this answer)

Answer (score 19):

I found 2 ways to display the file path in the Title bar of the gnome-terminal while editing a file with Vim.

The simpler (and better) way: Add the following line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set title
```

Which will show you at the top:

```
filename.ext (~/path_to_directory_where_your_file_is/) - VIM
```

The more complicated way will show you the absolute file path. It's [documented in a bit more detail in this blog post](http://sampsonchen.com/2012/11/05/vim-tip-setting-file-name-in-the-title-bar-not-the-status-bar/) I recently wrote.

Comment: The "set title" will show the file name on the terminal tab. Interesting feature.

Comment: Interesting as it is, doesn't answer the question asked. Also you assert it's better - but it might not be. For example if you your vim is open in terminal which is in full screen mode, title isn't visible. Thus downvote.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/), put in `.vimrc`:

```
let g:airline_section_c = '%<%F%m %#__accent_red#%{airline#util#wrap(airline#parts#readonly(),0)}%#__restore__#'
```

This is a modification of the airline default, changing `%f` by `%F`.

Answer (score 8):

The only way I found to get the full path of the file I'm working in is: `:echo expand('%:p')`.  You can re-map ctrl+g if you want, but I personally don't like shifting away from the standards too much.  I've mapped F7 like so:

```
map  <F7> <Esc>:echo expand('%:p')<Return>
```

Comment: `:help CTRL-G`, and look two paragraphs down for `CTRL-G` with count.

Comment: Thanks, @StefanMajewsky. `1 CTRL-G` shows full file name. I was searching for this option.

Comment: I love u Tim, this is the only way to absolutely show absolute path, even without `~`.

Answer (score 6):

I've always used `:f`, but the answer and links from @MichaelBerkowski are amazing!

`:f` shows the path, line count, modified state, current cursor position, and more...

I didn't know about <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> but it appears to be about the same.

Answer (score 5):

The statusline is very powerful and handy I think. Strait out of the box it will display filename, cursor position and some flags. But you want to do the same as me and replace the *filename*-part with the *full path* to the file.

So while editing my `.vimrc` my statusline could look something like this as default:

```
.vimrc                                                        26,16           7%
```

You could view your setting of the statusline with:

```
:set statusline?
```

But if you have not made any alterations and no module has changed it it would be empty. But by the examples in the help-section (`:help statusline`) you could find that the default is:

```
:set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

So include this in your `.vimrc` and change `%f` to `%F`. I also added added the filetype flag (`%y`) to my statusline since I find it convenient. So my resulting configuration looks like this:

```
:set statusline=%<%F\ %h%m%r%y%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

And the result would look something like this:

```
~/.vimrc [vim]                                                26,16           7%
```

Good reading:

- [The documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27statusline%27)
- [An excellent book to learn the basics](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/17.html)
- [There is lots here on stackoverflow!](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vim]+statusline)

*PS. I run vim 7.3*

Answer (score 4):

If you want the path to include resolved symlinks, use the following:

```
set statusline +=%{resolve(expand('%:p'))}\ %*
```

To keep the '~' abbreviation for your home directory, include `fnamemodify`

```
set statusline +=%{fnamemodify(resolve(expand('%:p')),':~')}\ %*
```

Comment: Both of these worked for me in VIM 7.4 using iTerm2 to SSH into Ubuntu 16.04 LTS