# Show vim tab line even if only one file is open

Tags: vim, tabs

I would like for vim to show the tab header (tab line) even if only one file is open.

For example, I open a file using vim. Then, I use `:tabnew` to open another file in a vim tab. Vim then displays a nice tab header at the top of the file. I would like this tab header to always be displayed (i.e. even if only one file is open in vim).

Also, not really a fan of the airline plugins, so not really looking for those kinds of answers.

[image]

Comment: How about asking Vim *first*: `:help 'showtabline'`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes sorry about that. I was doing `:help tabline` and didn't see anything. You just need to put `set showtabline=2` in your vimrc