# How to show constantly current working directory in vim

Tags: vim

A very simple question, is there some way to show constantly the current working directory at the bottom of the file opened by vim? Thanks.

Note this is a different question as here:
[How can I permanently display the path of the current file in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488717/how-can-i-permanently-display-the-path-of-the-current-file-in-vim)

There we want to show the full path of the current file viewed, but what I am thinking is to show both, maybe two lines on the bottom of file: one for full path currently viewed; the other for the current working directory. These two could be different as we can open a file that's not in the current working directory.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it by adding these lines in your .vimrc

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%!getcwd()
```

The first setting is to configure statusline to be always visible, second one is to add a current working directory to statusline.

More on

- [`:h laststatus`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27laststatus%27)
- [`:h statusline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27statusline%27)
- [`:h getcwd()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcwd%28%29)

---

Edit: This is an answer to OP's changed question:

It is not possible to have [two-line statusline](https://superuser.com/questions/242284/two-line-status-line-in-vim) (at least to my knowledge). But it is possible to add e.g. some formatting. So

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%F
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%{getcwd()}
```

To further study I recommend to read help I mentioned before. Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375240/a-more-useful-statusline-in-vim/5380230) might be of some interest.

Comment: A two-line statusline is possible if you're willing to recompile vim. The Patch is here: https://gist.github.com/h-east/3158492 & discussion of the patch with screenshots here https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/225