# modify Ctrl-G in Vim

Tags: vim, config

I am looking to modify Ctrl-G `<C-g>` in the following way:

Current Behavior:
`<C-g>`

`"test.txt" 89 lines --1%--`

What I want is to modify  so it's output looks like 1 Ctrl-G `1<C-g>`

`"~/Documents/test.txt" 89 lines --1%--`

if I make the following mapping:

`map <C-g> echo expand('%:p')`

I get:

`/home/me/Documents/test.txt`

I would like to push `<C-g>` and get:

`"~/Documents/test.txt" 89 lines --1%--`

Can you help me fix my mapping to get desired output?

I am piggy-backing heavily off this question:  [Display name of the current file in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111696/display-name-of-the-current-file-in-vim) by muthuh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
:nnoremap <c-g> 1<c-g>
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
:noremap <C-g> 1<C-g>
```

which avoids a recursion?

Comment: This works too, but I am accepting the nnoremap to map in normal mode only.

Comment: @posop Fair enough. Upvote would be nice, though, since it is the recursion that gets in the way of a naive mapping with `map`. :-)

Comment: I agree to that ;)

Comment: @steffen Thanks, upvote as well for your mode-specific solution.